# Text from my paragraphs appear above my blockquotes

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the first word of my paragraphs keep appearing above my blockquotes. My code structure looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
<style>

blockquote {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

p {
  width: 640px;
}

<!-- CSS style to put div side by side -->
        <style type="text/css">  
        .container { 
            width:600px; 
            height:190px;
        } 
        #ab-box { 
            float:left;
            width:360px; 
            height:160px; 
            background-color:white;
        } 
        #tb-box { 
            float:left; 
            width:180px; 
            height:160px; 
            background-color:white;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="ab-box">
    <blockquote style="border: 2px solid #666; padding: 10px; background-color: #fff; width: 240px"> <b>AUTHOR:</b>
      <br><br>{{NAME}}</blockquote>
  </div>
  <div id="tb-box">
    <blockquote style="border: 2px dotted #666; padding: 10px; background-color: #fff; width: 240px"> <b>PUBLISHED:</b>
      <br><br>December 1993</blockquote>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Dear *|SUBSCRIBER|* -&nbsp;<br /><br />We're happy to have you onboard!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

This isn't a perfect representation... But the word "Dear" in the paragraph below keeps appearing above the blockquotes for some reason. The rest of the paragraph moves just fine and is perfectly in line - it's just that one word. And if I duplicate the paragraph, I get the same issue. Please assist; thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

close your "style" tag

```
<style>

blockquote {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

p {
  width: 640px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your code has two errors: first of all, you opened the style tag two times, firstly after the head open and then after the comment

```
<!-- CSS style to put div side by side -->
```

Second, the comment is an Html comment, not a Css one: inside Style tags you cant use html comments

```
<!-- blabla -->
```

Instead, you have to write them like this

```css
body {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  /*
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  Multi line comment
  */
}
```

Here you can find a more detailed example.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_comments.asp

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much! You're awesome :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) If an answer resolve your issue, remember to mark it, so you'll help other users with your same problem. Happy coding!